# adding hyperlink to the date number in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, fullcalendar

I am trying to add a way for users to click on the actual number in the date box using fullcalendar v2. It will be directing to a page outside of fullcalendar. I have tried a few different solutions and can't get anything to work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Have tried this method:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

    if (allDay) {
        // Clicked on the entire day 

        if ($(jsEvent.target).is('div.fc-day-number')) {      
            // Clicked on the day number 

            $('#calendar') 
                window.location = "url";
        }
    }
}
```

Have tried this method editing fullcalendar.js, adding onclick to the table element:

```
numberCellHtml: function(row, col, date) {
    var classes;

    if (!this.dayNumbersVisible) { // if there are week numbers but not day numbers
        return '<td/>'; //  will create an empty space above events :(
    }

    classes = this.dayGrid.getDayClasses(date);
    classes.unshift('fc-day-number');

    return '' +
        '<td onclick="url" class="' + classes.join(' ') + '" data-date="' + date.format() + '">' +
            date.date() +
        '</td>';
},
```

Any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was quick. Maybe I should start asking every question that way I'll figure out my issues this quickly. (just kidding)

Turns out 'onclick' wasn't what it needed. It was looking for

ex:

```
numberCellHtml: function(row, col, date) {
    var classes;

    if (!this.dayNumbersVisible) { // if there are week numbers but not day numbers
        return '<td/>'; //  will create an empty space above events :(
    }

    classes = this.dayGrid.getDayClasses(date);
    classes.unshift('fc-day-number');

    return '' +
        '<td class="' + classes.join(' ') + '" data-date="' + date.format() + '"><a href ="http://www.google.com">' +
            date.date() +
        '</a></td>';
},
```